# How to create a survey-like android app where respondents can upload images

Tags: android, file-upload, email, account, survey

I am a beginner at programming in general, but I want to learn how to create an app where: Users create an account (email, name, username, password), answer a survey, upload an image, and send that image and survey data to a database/email where I can verify the information and send a response (either through the app or with an email).
As I am a beginner, I have no clue how to get started with this and what to use to accomplish each step. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need a database if your doing logins. Otherwise you would have to store the user/pass on the persons device, which sounds like a bad idea. Since you need a database for that anyway, I would use the database for getting the survey info and image as well. Besides, all you can do with android for email is launch an email client with stuff filled out already. To me that seems a bit amateur. Sure there are ways to send an email through the app, but its probably a pain in the butt. So your going to need a website(hosting plan I mean, no domain name needed) to store the database. There are probably some free places to store data if your desperate. Just dont use some fly-by-night website that will be gone next month and your app wont work anymore.

As far as getting to the surveys yourself, you can either just browse the database via PHP admin on godaddy, or probably set something up on the hosting plan to automatically send you the data each day via email. You could also make a website or backdoor on your app with the functionality you need to manage the survey replies.

After making a database and succesfully connecting via your app, you need to make an xml layout file for each screen. One for login, one for the survey, etc. And then the corresponding java file for each screen. Its not a very difficult first project but could still take a bout a month if your green like me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one step at a time:

1- Figureout a way to send a photo from gallery with some texts "survey answers" to an email address.
This doesn't need user account because the app can handle bundling a photo and the survey text in one message and send it to your email.

To do this:

A- Search how to let the user pick a photo from gallery let the app get its file path.
B- When you get the file path do some thing like this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// The intent does not have a URI, so declare the "text/plain" MIME type
emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"jon@example.com"}); // recipients
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://path/to/email/attachment"));
// You can also attach multiple items by passing an ArrayList of Uris
```

Now you can receive the user's photo and survey on your email. If you want to store these things in an online database, you can use services like Parse.com they are great at that.

2- Parse.com can help you link your app to an online database that you can manage. If you learn it, you can:

- Creates User accounts
- Store the surveys and photos in a database on their servers online
- Link the app to the database to show each user his survey and photos.

Parse.com have complete guide in how to integrate their service in your app.
The sad news is that Parse.com are closing in 2017, but you can still create apps using their services then they guide you to migrate your database to another online database provider. So to accomplish your app, you'll need some learning, but it's a lot of fun :)